# spring ldap outofmemory unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-security

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception


root cause 

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:215)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:118)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClientFactory.createPooledConnection(LdapClientFactory.java:46)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections.<init>(Connections.java:97)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool.getPooledConnection(Pool.java:114)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapPoolManager.getLdapClient(LdapPoolManager.java:310)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1572)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2625)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:288)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
    com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
    javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:134)
    org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:43)
    org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:254)
    org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:106)
    org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1434)
    org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1386)
    com.company.iss.services.ISSServiceImpl.login(ISSServiceImpl.java:98)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy55.login(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy56.login(Unknown Source)
    com.company.iss.services.UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:51)
    org.springframework.security.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:188)
    org.springframework.security.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:46)
    org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:82)
    org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:258)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 logs.
```

this is my spring ldap setting

```
<property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool">true</prop>
        <prop key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.initsize">1</prop>
        <prop key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize">1</prop>
        <prop key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize">1</prop>
    <prop key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout">300000</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

any comments why this cause outofmemory? my pool size is only 1?

Comment: Did you finally find a solution to that issue? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it has anything to do with LDAP or your pool size.  Perm gen is likely getting filled up.  I'd turn on visualvm and watch what's happening with memory when your app starts up to see if that's the case.

I'd also check the Tomcat logs to see if there was more, better information than this stack trace.